# Não consigo testar meu aplicativo Ionic: Cors error

Tags: ionic, angular

Estou tendo muitos problemas para testar meu aplicativo Ionic.
Como ele possui requisições HttpClient, estou tendo problemas com o Cors.
Pensei em gerar o build de produção e testar no celular, então eu testei:

```
cordova build android --prod
```

O app é gerado, eu copio para o meu celular e realizo a instalação, porém quando vou executar ele retorna:

> err_conecttion_refused: localhost:8080

Também tentei: cordova build android --prod --release
Mas nesse caso eu não consigo instalar o aplicativo.
Como vocês fazem pra testar aplicativos que tem requisições http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é a nova versão do cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.0 que quebra a compatibilidade com o Android 4.4.

A solução é passar para a versão 1.2.1:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
ionic cordova platforms remove android
rm -rf plugins
ionic cordova build android
```

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte! ;)

Comment: mas depois de fazer esses passos devo rodar com --prod --release ou só --prod?

Comment: pode rodar o `cordova build android --prod` no lugar do ultimo passo. 
Costume meu usar o ionic cordova build android ^^

Comment: Fiz dessa maneira mas agora o aplicativo inicia com uma tela branca e não sai disso :l

Comment: Conecta o celular no pc, executa `ionic cordova run android -lc`. 
No chrome acessa `chrome://inspect`, vc vai ver o dispositivo em **Remote Target** inspeciona e ve no console se aparece algum erro.

Comment: Se eu rodar com ionic cordova run android -lc o aplicativo funciona até ter alguma requisição http, porém não consigo realizar requisições por conta do cors, por isso gostaria de fazer o build da aplicação, mas quando dou o build --release não instala e o build normal o app da tela branca

Comment: você pode usar o release e ver se tem algum erro no terminal:

`ionic cordova run android -lc --release`

Acabaram minhas ideias. Desculpe :|
Boa sorte!

Comment: Tudo bem, só uma pergunta, é pra eu olhar o console daquele inspect do chrome?

Comment: Não. Ele não fica ativo quando você usa release. Os logs vão aparecer no local aonde você executou o comando( terminal, por ex.), isso acontece por causa do parâmetro `c` no comando